# JSON issue when parsing JSON from Newtonsoft.Json in Java

Tags: java, c#, json, parsing, networking

I run a WPF application that serializes an object into JSON with Newtonsoft.Json, and that works perfectly fine. That JSON looks like this:

```
"{\"Sender\":{\"ID\":0,\"Name\":\"Nebber\"},\"Content\":\"Some message\",\"Date\":\"17-Aug-20 11:53:20\"}"
```

However, as I want to parse that JSON into an object on my Java server application with gson, something weird happens. If I simply print the converted byte stream, I get the JSON string, but with an X in front:

```
"X"{"Sender":{"ID":0,"Name":"Nebber"},"Content":"Some message","Date":"17-Aug-20 11:53:20"}"
```

And if I debug the JSON string and select 'set value' (using IntelliJ IDE), the string comes out as:

```
"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000X\u0000\u0000\u0000{\"Sender\":{\"ID\":0,\"Name\":\"Nebber\"},\"Content\":\"Some message\",\"Date\":\"17-Aug-20 11:53:20\"}"
```

Now, I have noticed that Newtonsoft.Json adds escape characters, and I'm not sure if these could be the cause of the problem or not. Maybe it could be caused by endianness as well?

I'm very new to Java, as in I have only worked with it for a few days, so my guesses might be completely wrong.

Comment: What happened when you tried to deserialize the JSON to a java class object?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The JSON isn't in a format the the gson parser understands, so I get a 'java.lang.NullPointerException'. If, however, I substring the JSON in Java and cut away the first 8 characters before deserializing it I can successfully parse, it but that shouldn't be necessary.